# Call MangedBean using onSlide event instead of SlideEndEvent event

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Currently we are using ajax slideEnd event and in backEndBean we are doing some % calculation

```
<h:outputText id="brightness" value="#{brightnessBean.brightnessLevelValue} %" />
    <h:inputHidden id="brightnessLevel" value="#{brightnessBean.editingObj.brightnessLevel}" />
    <p:slider for="brightnessLevel" minValue="0" maxValue="255" step="1" >
        <p:ajax event="slideEnd" listener="#{brightnessBean.brightnessSildeEnd}" update="brightness"></p:ajax>
    </p:slider>
```

Our backendBean is doing some percentage calculation using

```
public void brightnessSildeEnd(SlideEndEvent endEvent) {
        brightnessLevelValue = (100 * endEvent.getValue()) / 255;
    }
```

But now we want to do this using **onSlide** event but **<p:ajax></p:ajax>** is not supporting this event.
**Please guide me the way we can display % when user uses slider instead of end of the slider.**

Comment: Which PF version are you using?

Comment: @WoAiNii we are  using 5.3

Comment: From [PF 5.3 docs](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_3.pdf) there's a `<p:slider onSlide="...">`, have you tried using it?

Comment: Yep like @WoAiNii said use `onSlide` client side call with a `p:remoteCommand` to call a backing bean.

Comment: @Melloware sure will try this and update.

Comment: I would not use Ajax for this and keep this at the client side. No need to bombard the server with requests while the user is sliding.

Comment: @JasperdeVries can you give an example to do this at client side.